# Stack overflow i guess while insmod

Tags: linux-kernel, stack-overflow, ubuntu-10.10

I have built kernel 2.6.35 on my system with some specific requirement. I also built some app defined module with the same kernel. I booted up the built version and I find it did not work properly as there is some gui and other modules missing problem. But the system booted up and I did a insmod app.ko. I faced a crash. I found out that it is a stack problem. A caller function in the APP is passing address of two local variable. like int a, b; add (&a, &b); I checked the values of &a and &b before passing and it remained non-null but when i receive the same in the calling function, both the &a, &b are NULL or some garbage value. I increased the stack size but nothing happened. When i skipped the function call, I could see that many allocation of memory has also failed. So I think it should be memory problem. Is there anything I should be checking for gcc option to define the stack or check for stack overflow. Any hints on this could help me a lot. Thanks in advance. I just made some abstract examples since the original code section takes lot of time to explain.

```
main()
    {

    struct DMAINFO* pDmaInfo;
    struct DESC* pDesc;
            /*  printk("The function aruguments are Desc = %p and DmaInfo %p", &pDesc, &pDmaInfo); */

    Create_DMA(&pDesc, &pDmaInfo);
    }


void Create_DMA(**ppDesc, **ppDmaInfor)
    {
    printk("The function aruguments are Desc = %p and DmaInfo %p", ppDesc, ppDmaInfo);
    }
```

The printk statement inside create_DMA gives me NULL values, but the same print statement in the main function before the create_DMA call has some values.

Comment: please post at least the code sample that calls `add(&a,&b)` and the code that "receives the same in the calling function". Just from reading that you could be returning the address stack variables.

Comment: main()
 {
 
 struct DMAINFO* pDmaInfo;
 struct DESC* pDesc;
 Create_DMA(&pDesc, &pDmaInfo);
 }


void Create_DMA(**ppDesc, **ppDmaInfor)
 {
 prink("The function aruguments are Desc = %p and DmaInfo %p", ppDesc, ppDmaInfor);
 }

Comment: don't post code in comments. Edit your question, and make sure you use the `{}` button in the editor so that it shows up properly in the preview.

Comment: OK Sorry. I have updated the original post. Let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 0):

`pDesc` and `pDmaInfo` is un-initialed before Create_DMA(), so it contains garbage value and causes the print statement in the main function before the create_DMA call outputs some values.

When Create_DMA() is called, Create_DMA() try to allocation memory and some other resources and put the result at `pDesc` and `pDmaInfo`. When Create_DMA() fails, the value of `pDesc` and `pDmaInfo` is undefined, depends on process of Create_DMA().

To avoid such problem, you should always init the `pDesc` and `pDmaInfo` and write the Create_DMA() carefully.

```
main()
    {
    ....
    struct DMAINFO* pDmaInfo = NULL;
    struct DESC* pDesc = NULL;
    ....
}
```